# Solr Server Posting Error

Tags: solr

How to post 5000 files to Solr server?
While posting by using command "java -jar post.jar dir/*.xml", command tool tells Argument list is too long.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest solution would be using a bash script like the following:

```
for i in $( ls *.xml); do
    cat $i | curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' -d @- http://localhost:8080/solr/update
    echo item: $i
done
```

which adds to Solr, using curl, all the xml files within the current directory.

Otherwise you can write a Java main similar to the one included in post.jar, which adds all the xml files within a directory instead of having to pass all of them as arguments.